# How to read a Protobuf that was written by a TFRecordWriter

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, protocol-buffers

I am trying to read data that was written with `tf.io.TFRecordWriter` as shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def _bytes_feature(value):
  """Returns a bytes_list from a string / byte."""
  if isinstance(value, type(tf.constant(0))):
    value = value.numpy() # BytesList won't unpack a string from an EagerTensor.
  return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

tfrecord_filename = "test.tfrecord"
with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(tfrecord_filename) as writer:
    for i in range(4):
        a  = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 5)
        a = tf.convert_to_tensor(a, dtype=tf.float32)
        a = tf.io.serialize_tensor(a)
        feature = {
          'a'   : _bytes_feature(a),
        }
        example_proto = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
        writer.write(example_proto.SerializeToString())
```

I am then using the schema as given by:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/feature.proto and https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto
along with protoc to decode it. The reading program is:

```
import test_pb2

parser = test_pb2.Example()
with open("test.tfrecord", "rb") as f:
    parser.ParseFromString(f.read())
    print(parser.feature)
```

Using the `ParseFromString` method I expect to be able to recover the data written after executing the above program but I consistently get:

```
RuntimeWarning: Unexpected end-group tag: Not all data was converted
```

What am I doing wrong?